# JSON Circular Object Type Reviver

Tags: javascript, json, object

I am building a web app game that uses custom circular objects that the user can manipulate and save. All of the objects are connected to a circular 'player' object that is stored using [Circular-JSON](https://github.com/WebReflection/circular-json).

The app requires that the object types be preserved, but JSON does not do so. I cannot declare the type for each individual object because the player could have a couple hundred objects of various types. I've seen some reviver's that are type specific, but not a generic one or one that would work with circular objects.

For example:

```
function Room(name, description){
            this.type = "room";
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.roomItems = [/*array of items randomly set*/];
    this.exits = [/*array of rooms set */];
}

function Item(name, description, weight){
            this.type = "item";
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.components = [/*array of items*/];
    this.contents = [];
    this.setContents = function(item){
        this.contents.push(item);
        this.weight += item.weight;
    }
}

function Player(startroom){
            this.type = "player"
    this.weightLimit = 20;
    this.totalWeight = 0;
    this.currentRoom = startroom; //this is a room
    this.playerItems = [/* An array of Items */]; 
    this.moveCount = 0;
}
```

The app saves and loads through:

```
function saveGame(){    
    var d = new Date()
    player.lastsave = d.toISOString();
    localStorage.setItem('player', CircularJSON.stringify(player));
}

function loadGame(){
    declareStart(); //loads the same as a start
    player =  CircularJSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('player', reviver)); 
}
```

The reviver I tried is as follows:

```
function reviver(k, v){
        switch (v.type) {
            case "room":
                $.extend(v, Room.prototype);
                break;
            case "item":
                $.extend(v, Item.prototype);
                break;
            case "player":
                $.extend(v, Player.prototype);
                break;
        }
        return v;
    }
```

The load replaces the new player with the player on local storage, but all of the objects lose their type in the process, which then loses functionality.

Does a reviver exist that would work? Is it possible to write one?

I guess the generic question would be, is there a way to store and retrieve circular objects whilst maintaining type?

Comment: using setPrototypeOf() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf. you can assign the proper prototypes in your reviver. alternatively, you can re-instantiate and then extend() with the serialized values.

Comment: "*a couple hundred objects of various types*" - uh, what? And why would storing the type not work?

Comment: @dandavis I added a sample of the reviver I built and it did not work. setPrototypeOf() is not supported by IE and Safari, so I used .extend with the prototype

Comment: @Bergi storing the type was the first step I was missing, dunno why I thought I couldn't.

Comment: @kahjav: there is a polyfill for setPrototypeOf() on the MDN page for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kahjav You definitely can revive the types by using `Object.create`, using introspection on the name of the constructor method & using a convention of naming the circular reference at a key that's the same as the lowercased name of the constructor. See my gist at:
https://gist.github.com/jameswomack/6e6462f9c6ae5d9b9072

Due to how the CircularJSON module was created, you cannot keep the type for both the parent object and it's circular reference using CircularJSON alone.

There's essentially a two step process

```
function get(key, Proto) {
  var result = JSON.parse(this.store[key]);
  return key === Proto.name.toLowerCase() ? reviveFromJSONResult(result, Proto) : result;
}

function reviveFromJSONResult(result, Proto) {
  var value = Object.create(Proto);
  for (var key in result) {
    value[key] = result[key];
  }
  value[Proto.name.toLowerCase()] && (value[Proto.name.toLowerCase()] = value);
  return value;
}

var person = get('person', Person);
```

You pass the key and the Constructor name (you could even simplify this further by following a convention), parse the object at the key and then inject it into a new Constructor. Thereafter, you simply assign to the lowercased version of the constructor name. You could also loop through the values and find the '~'.